phinx migrate no me funciona con variables de entorno
Tengo los siguientes archivos:
phinx.php:
    <?php

require __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';

return [
    'paths' => [
        'migrations' => 'db/migrations',
        'seeds' => 'db/seeds'
    ],
    'environments' => [
        'default_migration_table' => 'phinxlog',
        'default_environment' => 'development',
        'development' => [
            'adapter' => 'mysql',
            'host' => $_ENV["DB_HOST"],
            'name' => $_ENV['DB_NAME'],
            'user' => $_ENV['DB_USER'],
            'pass' => $_ENV['DB_PASS'],
            'port' => $_ENV['DB_PORT'],
            'charset' => $_ENV['DB_CHARSET'],
        ],
    ],
    'version_order' => 'creation'
];

bootstrap.php:
    <?php 

require __DIR__. '/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

// Imprimir las variables de entorno para verificar
var_dump($_ENV);
?>

.env:
ENVIRONMENT=dev

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=usuario
DB_PASS=**********
DB_NAME=ejemplo_env
DB_PORT=3306
DB_CHARSET=utf8mb4

vendor/bin/phinx create CreateUsersTable

Crea el archivo de migración satisfactoriamente
vendor/bin/phinx migrate

No hace la migración, cuando está con las variables de entorno, si pongo los datos originales, crea las tablas en BD.
using config parser php
using migration paths 
 - /var/www/html/migracion-php-env/db/migrations
using seed paths 
 - /var/www/html/migracion-php-env/db/seeds
warning no environment specified, defaulting to: development
using adapter mysql
Could not determine database name! Please specify a database name in your config file.

